# Flexsurvreg with treatment covariate. Separating variance covariance matrix

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am using `flexsurvreg()` to fit and extrapolate parametric models on survival data. I use the treatment group as a covariate to make a proportional hazard model. I need a variance covariance matrix separately for the two treatment groups but I am unable to find out how I separate the groups after fitting the parametric model.

```
weib <- flexsurvreg(Surv(os_mnts, censoring) ~ treat, data = date_ex, dist = "weibull")
```

An example of the data is below. I do have treat == control as well even though it does not show here.

```
#sx_date    last_fup_date censoring   sex treat     os_mnts
#   <date>     <date>            <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
# 1 2010-06-03 2013-08-10            0     1 treatment   38.2 
# 2 2013-06-10 2014-09-09            1     1 treatment   15.0 
# 3 2014-11-05 2015-07-03            0     0 treatment    7.89
# 4 2011-03-07 2014-08-10            1     1 treatment   41.1 
# 5 2010-03-06 2013-12-11            0     1 treatment   45.2 
# 6 2011-09-08 2015-01-01            0     1 treatment   39.8 
# 7 2008-10-09 2016-06-02            1     0 treatment   91.8 
# 8 2010-02-11 2015-01-02            1     1 treatment   58.7 
# 9 2009-08-06 2014-07-06            0     1 treatment   59.0 
#10 2011-07-03 2016-04-03            0     0 treatment   57.0
```

When I call `vcov(weib)` to get the variance covariance matrix, I get the following.

```
#                     shape        scale treattreatment
#shape           0.0218074155 -0.004631324  -0.0001595603
#scale          -0.0046313242  0.007912648  -0.0068951896
#treattreatment -0.0001595603 -0.006895190   0.0138593195
```

However, I need two variance covariance matrices (1 for each treatment group) with shape and scale only.

I have tried searching for way to separate the matrix itself and to subset the weib object. However I cannot find how to do either of these things. Does anyone know how I can get separate matrices out of this?

Comment: Why are you asking for such a result? And what do you intend to do with the result if you can get it (which I somehow doubt)?

Comment: I am interested in obtaining the separate variance covariance matrices because I want to perform cholesky decomposition. This I will in a further step use to perform a probabilistic sensitivity analysis

Comment: As always ... SO questions need  MCVE for testing and demonstration purposes. Questions without the data to construct a working example are often closed. The should be a link to how this is best implemented for "R questions" on the page that exists for the [r] tag.